# Div displaying below div instead of at top of it? (absolute position, margin-top/left 0)

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

I have a div (#homepage_web_title_webDesign) that, by my understanding, should be in the top left corner of its parent div (#homepage_web_drop_webDesign_wrap), but instead it's displaying just below it.  Any help is greatly appreciated!  The JSFiddle includes the reset I'm using.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Y7UGp/3/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="homepage_web_drop_webDesign_wrap" style="background-color:rgba(0,255,0,.1);">
    <img id="homepage_web_drop_webDesign" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/Piratey_transparent_background.svg/383px-Piratey_transparent_background.svg.png" />
    <div id="homepage_web_title_webDesign">Web Design</div>
    <div id="homepage_web_description_webDesign">Creative Web Design should fit your budget and satisfy both you and your customers.</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    #homepage_web_drop_webDesign_wrap {
        position:absolute;
        margin-left:0%;
        margin-top:0%;
        height:320px;
        width:260px;
    }
    #homepage_web_drop_webDesign {
        display:inline;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    #homepage_web_title_webDesign {
        font-family:ElectrofiedBoldItalic;
        color:rgb(120,91,67);
        position:absolute;
        background-color:purple;
        margin-left:0%;
        margin-top:0%;
        z-index:65;
    }
```

(I replaced the image with a random one from google, but the dimensions are set with CSS so it doesn't matter obviously.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set only `position: absolute;` with no value for `top`, `bottom`, `left` or `right`. So the element is placed where it appears in the normal flow. When you set one of those values it gets positioned accordingly.

See this new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dV5ch/).

Comment: It is apparent that I have no Idea what I'm doing.  Thank you, kind sir.  http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/400x/31612783.jpg

Answer (score 1):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7UGp/4/)***

[`margin-left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/margin-left)`:0` is an offset of the current placement. You should use

```
left:0;
top:0;
```

if you want it to be placed over the previous element